# How to structure JSON data in mongoDB?

Tags: json, mongodb, database-design

I am webcrawling a news paper website.

The site contains articles, that contains a title, some text, timestamp, author, and a comment section.

The comment section contains comments from diffrent registered users, where they can comment the article, upvote comments, and reply to other comments.

I am using MongoDB (beginner), and my question is what would be keept in a JSON object.

For example, would each news article be a single object, with all user comments inside it. Or would it be more readable to have each text/comment as a  own object.

```
{"article": {
"id": "title of article",
"text": "text of article",
"author": "author of article",
"date": "date",
"comment_section": {
    "user": "username",
    "text": "text from comment",
    "upvotes": int,
},
}}
```

Or something like:

```
{"text": {
    "text_type": "article text or comment",
    "text": "text of article or comment",
    "date": "date",
    "author": "author of article or comment author",
    "upvotes": int,
}}
```

Where the first example would have fewer objects, but lots of stuff in them, and the latter, lots of objects, but not to much data in them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full power of json lies in it being a tree, so a single document can contain all its data within. You can add indexes on subdocuments and projections to query only the necessary parts of your document.

However, if you expect to have huge comments sections, embedded comments might be an issue, as then mongodb has to read up the whole document, add a new comment to the comment list, and write it back.

Ideally, you'd go for a middle solution: keep the comments embedded until there are less than 20-50 (which are also rendered along with the article and a 'next comments' button), and then switch to keep incoming comments in an extracted comments collection. That way, you can render your article with a single mongo query, effectively making one mongo query per user interaction - which is the preferred way of DB design.

With mongo, you'll always have to leverage between object size + amount of updates against the cost of extracting that data to an external collection and doing extra queries against it.

Comment: As I understood, you suggest the first option, do you also suggest to store all diffrent news articles in the same object as well?

Comment: With my experience, I'd suggest to have a collection for articles, and store the first N comments, that you plan to display on page render anyway, in there too. So that for rendering the article page, you get all the data in a single mongo query. When you have more than N comments, place the extra to a separate collection, because it can easily grow to thousands of comments on a single article, which would make the article's document too costly to read or modify.